How to make Files recognise second monitor size
I have two monitors, one is smaller than the ohter.  When I open Files and it opens on the smaller screen, its height is the same as the larger monitor and so the top bar of Files isn't on the screen. I have to use the 'View split on left/right' keyboard shortcut to push it to the side of the monitor for it to adopt the correct dimensions for the smaller screen.
This only seems to happen with Files but not ohter programs.  Is there a fix for this?  I would like to open with the correct dimensions of whatever monitor it opens on.
Using Ubuntu 22.04, Files 42.6
